# Repeating a countdown timer 'X' amount of times when finished

Tags: python, tkinter, clock

I am creating a countdown tournament clock in Python. The program gathers an integer input, say **X**, from a Tkinter entry box. The program also collects user input on how long the countdown should be. When the countdown ends, the program should repeat the countdown **X** times.

The amount of times it should repeat is stored in a variable called **levels**

When the 'set' button is pressed, the 'start' and 'stop' buttons appear.

```
# When the set button is pressed, this
# function gets called
def Get_Time(self):

    self.time_display = Label(self.time_frame, 
    font=('Helvetica', 124 , "bold"), 
    bg = 'gray35', fg = 'yellow')
    self.time_display.place(x=430, y=240)

    #create other label and details, print blind level and prizes
    blind_level = Label(self.window, text="Blinds", 
    font=("helvetica",42, "bold"), bg='gray35',fg='yellow')
    blind_level.place(x=523, y=470)

    try:
        # Total amount of time in seconds
        m = (int(self.minute_combobox.get())*60)
        s = (int(self.second_combobox.get()))
        self.time_left = m + s

        # If the user try to set the default time(0:0:0) then
        # a warning message will display
        if s == 0 and m == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning('Warning!',\
            'Not a valid time!')
        else:
            # Start Button
            start_button = Button(self.button_frame, text='Start', 
            font=('Helvetica',12), bg="green", fg="white", 
            command=self.Threading)
            start_button.place(x=160, y=0)

            # Pause Button
            pause_button = Button(self.button_frame, text='Pause', 
            font=('Helvetica',12), bg="red", fg="white",
            command=self.pause_time)
            pause_button.place(x=240, y=0)
    except Exception as es:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!", \
        f"Error due to {es}")

# Creating a thread to run the show_time function
def Threading(self):
    
    self.x = Thread(target=self.start_time, daemon=True)
    self.x.start()
```

The start time function:

```
def start_time(self):
    
    self.pause = False
    

    while self.time_left > 0:
        mins, secs = divmod(self.time_left, 60)

        hours = 0
        if mins > 60:
            mins = divmod(mins, 60)

        self.time_display.config(text=f"{mins}: {secs}")
        self.time_display.update()
        # sleep function: for 1 second
        time.sleep(1)
        self.time_left = self.time_left -1
                
        #print what the current blind level is!
            
            
            
        if self.pause == True:
            break
```

Initially I thought I could wrap a for loop around the while statement in my *start_time* function, such as:

```
for x in range(0,levels):
       <while loop and rest of code>
```

But the program does not repeat and merely just ends. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to reset `self.time_left` back to `m + s` at the end of the for loop.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [answer] and [mre]. While it's [good and desirable to answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow, they should be questions that are suitable for the site - meaning that the code is reduced to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue; that the issue is a real issue and not caused by a simple typo or logical error (**unless** the point is "why does doing it this way have this strange result?"); and that the question is clear, specific and not a duplicate.